# Why does WSO2AM execute count query against mb_metadata table over and over again?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have enabled advanced throttling for WSO2AM 2.6.0. Once this was enabled and the execution plans were appropriately created, we are noticing that over 35M select count queries per hour are executing against MB_METADATA table.

Also, MB_METADATA and MB_CONTENT table are constantly growing and the row count never goes down.

I have disabled all statistics as well as tracing. we have 4 WSO servers, each one running independently with the gateway, key manager, and traffic manager on the same box. The DB is oracle.

we are seeing this query run 35 million times / hr:

SELECT COUNT(MESSAGE_ID) AS count
FROM MB_METADATA
WHERE QUEUE_ID=:1
AND MESSAGE_ID BETWEEN :2 AND :3
AND DLC_QUEUE_ID=-1

I would expect the table sizes to be manageable and this query not be run at this high of a rate.

Any suggestions on what might be going on? may be a configuration that I need to disable?

Comment: Are you sharing the DB among all nodes?

Comment: Yes - The DB is shared across all 4 nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing the MB database is not correct. Each traffic manager node should have its own MB database, and it can be the default H2 one.

Quoted from docs:

> Do not share the WSO2_MB_STORE_DB database among the nodes in an Active-Active set-up 
>   or Traffic Manager HA scenario, because each node should have its own local WSO2_MB_STORE_DB 
>   database to act as separate Traffic Managers.
>
> The latter mentioned DBs can be either H2 DBs or any RDBMS such as MySQL.
>
> If the database gets corrupted then you need to replace the database with a fresh database 
>   that is available in the product distribution.

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Installing+and+Configuring+the+Databases